# Consider the differential equation $dy/dt=ay-b$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $Y(t)=y-y_e$ ($y_e $ is equilibrium). Thus $Y(t)$ is the deviation from the equilibrium solution. Find the differential equation satisfied by $Y(t)$.

I solved for the general solution and got $y=(b/a)\pm ke^{at}$ and that $y_e=\frac{b}{a}$. But after this I really don't know what to do. It says the answer is $Y'=aY$.

Answer (score 2):

$y=(b/a)-ke^{at}$ and that $y_e=b/a\implies Y=y-y_e=-ke^{at}$

Now, differentiating last equation w.r.t. $t$ gives,

$Y'=-ake^{at}=a(-ke^{at})=aY$

Comment: I should have figured that. Thanks!